# iCarousel loading UIViews from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, icarousel

Hi I included iCarousel in my app for showing list of views. I am facing an issue now.

1. If i set number of items visible as 3, multiples of 3 index view are displayed
2. If i didn't set that first and last index of icarousel view is displayed.

I am so confused about the concept of reusing view in iCarousel.

Here is my code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{



ViewArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<26; i++) {
 [ViewArray addObject:views];
    [carousel1 reloadData];

}
NSLog(@"%@",ViewArray);
}


- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
//return the total number of items in the carousel
return 26;
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
 UIView *sub=nil;
 if (view==nil) {


view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 387)];

    capitalBG.frame=CGRectMake(28, 29, 221, 329);
    capitalBG.tag=11;
    [view addSubview:capitalBG];

    capitalImage.frame=CGRectMake(28, 29, 221, 329);
           [view addSubview:capitalImage];
    capitalImage.tag=12;
    smallBG.frame=CGRectMake(678, 111, 198, 166);
           [view addSubview:smallBG];
    smallBG.tag=21;
    smallImage.frame=CGRectMake(678, 111, 198, 166);
           [view addSubview:smallImage];
    smallImage.tag=22;

}

else
{

}

capitalBG.frame=CGRectMake(28, 29, 221, 329);
[capitalBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
[view addSubview:capitalBG];

capitalImage.frame=CGRectMake(28, 29, 221, 329);
[capitalImage setImage:[[[Global ImageCollection]objectForKey:@"CapitalWrite"]objectAtIndex:index]];
[view addSubview:capitalImage];

smallBG.frame=CGRectMake(678, 111, 198, 166);
[smallBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
[view addSubview:smallBG];

smallImage.frame=CGRectMake(678, 111, 198, 166);
[smallImage setImage:[[[Global ImageCollection]objectForKey:@"SmallWrite"]objectAtIndex:index]];
[view addSubview:smallImage];
 return view;
}


- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
{
if (option == iCarouselOptionSpacing)
{
    return value * 1.1f;
}

if (option==iCarouselOptionVisibleItems) {
    return 3;
}
return value;
}
```

Comment: @08442 i havig array of ivies with different images i need to paint on that imageview.. When i tried for same image in all views it worked well.. When i combined all those in array iam facing this issue,,,

Comment: allocate the subViews-capitalBG.frame=[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrameCGRectMake(28, 29, 221, 329)];,do the same for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not getting what you asked for Clearly. check the code for Implementation  of I-carousal to display Images.

```
     - (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
  {
//add all your images to an array,and use that array for count. 

return [items count];
 }



     - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index     reusingView:(UIView *)view
  {
    //create new view if no view is available for recycling
if (view == nil)
{
    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 215.0f, 155.0f)];
    ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.items objectAtIndex:index ]];

    view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
}

return view;
```

}

```
   - (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option          withDefault:(CGFloat)value
   {
//customize carousel display

        return value+0.1;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer... U have provided the code for using UIImageView and the images are from Array.. I'm trying to display UIView which is in Array..

Comment: what do you want to display on view

Comment: It have UIimageviews buttons sliders,etc @user1931314

Comment: add all subViews to the carousalView in the method  - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index     reusingView:(UIView *)view
  {   }

Comment: I have tried that method too...but still i get my first and last view only.. Inbetween views are displayed while scrolling when it comes to view it hides..Check my code pls..

Comment: @Vishnu Dany, I got the same issue, could you please show how you did it?